# Is `std::normal_distribution` guaranteed to be ok with standard deviation 0?

Tags: c++, random, c++11, normal-distribution

In the gcc implementation this works trivially; the parameters are only applied [as simple multiply and shift of the actual algorithm's output](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00987_source.html#l01636). But I could imagine other algorithms to have problems with a special case like this. Should I better build in an external safe-guard, or is it fine to just give `std::normal_distribution`'s constructor a 0 as the standard deviation parameter to get a "non-random distribution", i.e. one that always yields the mean value?

(Performance aside)

Comment: Perhaps this question could use a little more backstory. Why would it not be okay?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If the implementation ever divided by the standard deviation, I suppose.

Comment: I like how you mention performance on a question about a RNG that only produces one value ever. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard says the following (§26.5.8.4.4):

```
explicit normal_distribution(RealType mean = 0.0, RealType stddev = 1.0);
    Requires: 0 < stddev.
```

As such a standard derivation of `0` is explicitly forbidden by the standard and therefore not guaranteed to work. Therefore building an external safeguard seems like a good idea

Even if the typical implemention would work on a standard derivation of 0 (not sure if that is the case), I could imagine an implementation which tests for such a case and throws an exception when the standard derivation is zero and throws an exception if it is not (to ensure that the code is portable). As an alternative it is possible that the code will divide by the standard derivation somewhere, which would also be problematic with a derivation of `0`.

Comment: is there a place where we can find the standard ?

Comment: @user908821: the ISO comittee sell them, you might obtain a lower price from your national body. Otherwise, most people should be satisfied with prior drafts, such as [n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) or the next draft [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (this link appear not to be working)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a standard deviation of 0. From the standard, section 26.5.8.5.1:

```
explicit normal_distribution(RealType mean = 0.0, RealType stddev = 1.0);
Requires: 0 < stddev.
```

Using a value of 0 would result in undefined behavior, so you'll need to special-case that value.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous writers pointed out, the normal_distribution function's behavior is only defined for stddev>0.

I'd just like to add that this makes a lot of sense mathematically: For the stddev (width) =0 the Gaussian normal distribution becomes the Dirac delta function.

The Dirac delta function is defined to be ==0 everywhere except for x==0, where it is undefined. However, every integral over the delta function that includes x==0 within its integration limits is defined to be 1, while an integral not including x==0 is 0.

This behavior cannot be represented correctly within the definition of float/double numbers, therefore a normal distribution with stddev=0 has to remain undefined.

Comment: Hm. Floating-point numbers are actually just a finite subset of the reals, so the PDF is in fact a superposition of finitely many Dirac peaks anyway, not a proper function on ℝ. By choosing σ=0, we simply restrict the distribution to just one of them, rather than some 2²⁰ as they otherwise are. So I'd say the behaviour _can_ be represented. But then I'm a physicist, we pretend all the time the Dirac distribution is a well-behaved function; _usually_ nothing dramatic goes wrong...

Comment: well, I'm a physicist myself, so essentially I agree. Still this should be something the programmer should decide him/herself in a specific piece of code, so I think it's a good thing to leave it undefined in the standard.

Comment: So then the PDF is t → δ(t-μ).  Thus, if X is a random variable on the distribution, then X = μ almost surely.  It's certainly possible to assign reasonable behavior in the case σ=0.